# How to use scale factor to scale image in Swift

Tags: swift, image

I got a large image with 1920x1080 pixels. I'm trying to scale Image with 2 differents ways:

> First: using CIFilter

```
    func resize(image: UIImage, scale: Float, aspect: Float = 1) -> UIImage? {
    return autoreleasepool(invoking: {
        [weak self] () -> UIImage? in

        var filter: CIFilter! = CIFilter(name: "CILanczosScaleTransform")!
        filter.setValue(CIImage(image: image), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter.setValue(NSNumber(value: scale as Float), forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
        filter.setValue(NSNumber(value: aspect as Float), forKey: kCIInputAspectRatioKey)

        var result: UIImage?
        var cgImage: CGImage? = nil
        if let outputImage = filter.outputImage {
            cgImage = self?.ctx?.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)
        }
        if let cgImg = cgImage {
            result = self?.convertUIImage(fromCGImage: cgImg)
        }
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            self?.ctx?.clearCaches()
        }
        cgImage = nil
        filter.setValue(nil, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter.setValue(nil, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
        filter.setValue(nil, forKey: kCIInputAspectRatioKey)
        filter.setDefaults()
        filter = nil
        return result
    })
}
```

> Second: using UIImage()

```
func scaleImage(scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        if let cgImage = self.cgImage {
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

But I realized that the scale factor in two methods produced conflicting results. For example, I set scale equal to 2
But in first method: new image is size `(3840x2160)`, and second is `(960x540)`.

I'm really confused. Can anyone explain me why this happened
In the future when using a new function have parameter `scale` how do I know when scale make my image smaller and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

By default image has scale, its can any value. In began your image scale can be bigger than 2, that why your second way your image received smaller. Try this.

```
func scaleImage(image: UIImage, scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let size = CGSize(width: image.size.width * scale, height: image.size.height * scale)
    let drawRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)

    image.draw(in: drawRect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```